# How to set variable values based on which column number contains a string

Tags: r

I have a sheet formatted like so :

```
F   NF  C   NF  C   F   C   F   NF
F   NF  C   C   F   NF  NF  C   F
NF  C   F   F   NF  C   C   F   NF
NF  C   F   C   F   NF  F   NF  C
C   F   NF  F   NF  C   NF  C   F
C   F   NF  NF  C   F   F   NF  C
F   C   NF  NF  F   C   C   NF  F
F   C   NF  C   NF  F   NF  F   C
NF  F   C   F   C   NF  C   NF  F
NF  F   C   C   NF  F   F   C   NF
C   NF  F   F   C   NF  NF  F   C
C   NF  F   NF  F   C   F   C   NF
```

I want to use this sheet to set values to certain items, then do a bunch of stuff (the specifics of which I don't think are worth discussing). I want to set variables "a", "b" and "c" to be equal to the position of NF within the 3 different strings( F, NF and C). For example, I want to use a for loop to read the first row and set a to be 2, b to be 1 (because NF is in the "first" column of the second set of three columns) and c to be 3 then do a bunch of stuff (because NF is in the "third" column of the third set of three columns). After that I want it to read the second row and set a to be 2, b to be 3 and c to be 1.

I can't think of a way to do this other than use an ugly amount of if statements. Is there an alternative?

thanks

Comment: "Sheet" is rather vague, and inapplicable in the R context (I assume you're coming from Excel). Put in your question the result of a `dput` statement on your input data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `apply` a simple function to each row of the table, or in this case, pick out particular columns of the table and `apply` a function to each row in those columns:

```
> text = "F   NF  C   NF  C   F   C   F   NF
+ F   NF  C   C   F   NF  NF  C   F
+ NF  C   F   F   NF  C   C   F   NF
+ NF  C   F   C   F   NF  F   NF  C
+ C   F   NF  F   NF  C   NF  C   F
+ C   F   NF  NF  C   F   F   NF  C
+ F   C   NF  NF  F   C   C   NF  F
+ F   C   NF  C   NF  F   NF  F   C
+ NF  F   C   F   C   NF  C   NF  F
+ NF  F   C   C   NF  F   F   C   NF
+ C   NF  F   F   C   NF  NF  F   C
+ C   NF  F   NF  F   C   F   C   NF"
> x = read.table(text=text)
> a = apply(x[1:3], 1, function(vec) which(vec == "NF"))
> a
 [1] 2 2 1 1 3 3 3 3 1 1 2 2
> b = apply(x[4:6], 1, function(vec) which(vec == "NF"))
> b
 [1] 1 3 2 3 2 1 1 2 3 2 3 1
> c = apply(x[7:9], 1, function(vec) which(vec == "NF"))
> c
 [1] 3 1 3 2 1 2 2 1 2 3 1 3
```

The second argument to `apply` tells it which dimension of the table you want to apply the function to, 1 being the rows and 2 the columns.